# Error updating h:form from p:commandButton on JBoss 7.1.x

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jboss, wildfly

The following .xhtml is not working on JBoss 7.1.0/7.1.1 with PrimeFaces 5.3. It does work with WildFly, though, but I need the project to run on both platforms:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head></h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form id="form1">
            <p:commandButton id="btn1"
                             update="@form"
                             value="Update Form 1"/>
        </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

The following error is thrown:

```
10:41:21,892 SCHWERWIEGEND [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application]  (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Error Rendering View[/test.xhtml]: org.primefaces.expression.ComponentNotFoundException: Cannot find component for expression "@form" referenced from "btn1".
    at org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade.cannotFindComponent(SearchExpressionFacade.java:673) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade.resolveClientIds(SearchExpressionFacade.java:242) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at org.primefaces.util.AjaxRequestBuilder.addExpressions(AjaxRequestBuilder.java:92) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at org.primefaces.util.AjaxRequestBuilder.update(AjaxRequestBuilder.java:85) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.buildAjaxRequest(CoreRenderer.java:362) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.buildRequest(CommandButtonRenderer.java:123) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.encodeMarkup(CommandButtonRenderer.java:65) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.encodeEnd(CommandButtonRenderer.java:54) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:89) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeContent(DialogRenderer.java:186) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeMarkup(DialogRenderer.java:115) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeEnd(DialogRenderer.java:47) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.togglz.servlet.TogglzFilter.doFilter(TogglzFilter.java:100) [togglz-servlet-2.1.0.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at de.somepackage.util.filters.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:25) [expokat-ejb-0.5.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at de.somepackage.util.filters.SessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(SessionTimeoutFilter.java:31) [expokat-ejb-0.5.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]

10:41:21,909 INFO  [de.somepackage.util.ExceptionHandler]  (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Error in 'ComponentNotFoundException': org.primefaces.expression.ComponentNotFoundException: Cannot find component for expression "@form" referenced from "btn1".
    at org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade.cannotFindComponent(SearchExpressionFacade.java:673) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade.resolveClientIds(SearchExpressionFacade.java:242) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at org.primefaces.util.AjaxRequestBuilder.addExpressions(AjaxRequestBuilder.java:92) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at org.primefaces.util.AjaxRequestBuilder.update(AjaxRequestBuilder.java:85) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.buildAjaxRequest(CoreRenderer.java:362) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.buildRequest(CommandButtonRenderer.java:123) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.encodeMarkup(CommandButtonRenderer.java:65) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.encodeEnd(CommandButtonRenderer.java:54) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:89) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeContent(DialogRenderer.java:186) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeMarkup(DialogRenderer.java:115) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeEnd(DialogRenderer.java:47) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.togglz.servlet.TogglzFilter.doFilter(TogglzFilter.java:100) [togglz-servlet-2.1.0.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at de.somepackage.util.filters.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:25) [expokat-ejb-0.5.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at de.somepackage.util.filters.SessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(SessionTimeoutFilter.java:31) [expokat-ejb-0.5.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
```

Comment: @Kukeltje thank you, that is the problem. Please provide this as an answer, then I will accept that.

Comment: Ahhhhh... I don't care about reputation points in cases of hints/small suggestions like this and carefully written answers like @BalusC wrote. Now he removed it and there is nothing. Now I am either forced to write an extensive answer like he already did or do not provide an answer... :-(  Can you undelete an answer or maybe he can...

Comment: and btw, this is not related to a dialog, right? Removing it will still make it fail (as stated in my first and later removed comment)

Comment: @Kukeltje yes, it does/did. I related it to the dialog because originally, it was in an included file (which I got from another project, hence the wrong xmlns).

Comment: For next questions: [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wildfly by default uses a JSF2.2 implementation, while JBoss 7.1(.1) uses a JSF 2.1 implementation. Your code assumes a JSF 2.2 implementation by using the corresponding `xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"` namespace declaration. My suggestion was to correct that.

In an already removed answer, @BalusC explained what actually happens. For the facelets page, there is xml wise no error. You have an `h:form` and the corresponding namespace declaration. The `h:form` is however not interpreted as a jsf tag by the jsf 2.1 implementation since it does not have the correct namespace and it is effectively plain text. You could check this by removing the `update="@form"` from the `<p:commandButton>` and looking at the generated source in the browser. You'll see an `<h:form...>` there. The stacktrace also does not show any indication of an h:form being present (also courtesy to @BalusC) and so since there is no jsf form component being created, you run into the error you get.